# Calendar using daylight saving time when it shouldn't

Tags: java

A program I'm making is turning hex values into decimal. The decimal value represents the time since 1/1/2010 in seconds. I am using the Calendar methods to add the seconds to the date to get a final date/time. When I call the .useDaylightTime() it returns false yet the value I get is if it was using DST. Am I overlooking something?

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class timeSince {

    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String hex = input.nextLine();
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
        System.out.println(zone.useDaylightTime());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(zone);
        cal.set(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(hex,16));
        Date newDate = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(newDate));

    }

}
```

Comment: What's your hex input and expected and actual outputs?

Comment: I don't see where in your code it's "turning hex values into decimal" at all.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(hex,16) turns the hex into decimal

Comment: No, it turns the hex into an int. An int only has a representation (decimal or hex) when it is printed. As an int, where it lives in the computer's memory, it's just a bit pattern. There is no such thing as a representation inherent in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone used for formatting is set on the DateFormat.

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(newDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

As [k5_ said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751641/calendar-using-daylight-savings-when-it-shouldnt/51751850#51751850) the `SimpleDateFormat` is not using the same timezone as `Calendar`. Because of that the difference between your JVM system time zone and `EST` used to create `Calendar` is added to `newDate` when it's formatted. You are most likely in the `America/New_York` timezone yourself. This timezone is currently observing DST so when you print the `newDate` you see the value with DST.

`EST` is not a valid timezone, `ZoneId.of("EST")` will fail. `EST` is just the non-DST half of `America/New_York`, the other half is `EDT`. To correctly handle DST change use `America/New_York`.

All these problems can be avoided by using `java.time`

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.of(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, zone);
date = date.plusSeconds(13);
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(date.format(format)); // 2010/01/01 00:00:13
```